# GraphQL queries take time to execute and failed with Errors

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs

Sitecore instance running on `Sitecore 10.3, JSS, nextjs` with Graphql locally, I did enable graphql `master endpoint` to execute graphql queries.

It was taking such a long time to execute simple queries with `GraphiQL GUI.`

**Query code:**

```
query GetChildren($itemId: String!){
  item(path:$itemId){
    name
    hasChildren
    children{
      name
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Noticed the following errors in the log file.

```
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: The request queue limit of the session is exceeded.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.QueueRef()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSession()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.GetSessionStateItem()
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.BeginAcquireState(Object source, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
   
Exception: Polly.CircuitBreaker.BrokenCircuitException
Message: The circuit is now open and is not allowing calls.
Source: Polly
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitStateController`1.OnActionPreExecute()
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__181`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsync>d__121`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Wrap.PolicyWrapEngine.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.<<ImplementationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass181_0`1.<<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.RetrySyntaxAsync.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<WaitAndRetryAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__181`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsync>d__121`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Wrap.PolicyWrapEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__8`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsync>d__121`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAndCaptureAsync>d__139`1.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ExecuteRequest>b__0()
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.Execute[T](Func`1 action, String requestUri)
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.ResourceConnector`1.Request(String endpoint, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.CES.Discovery.EndpointSource.GetEndpoint(String serviceName)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.RequestGeoIpService(String ip)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.SitecoreProvider.GetWhoIsInformationByIp(String ip)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Fetcher.Providers.LookupGeoIpFetcher.CallLookupService(GeoIpRequest geoIpRequest)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Fetcher.Providers.LookupGeoIpFetcher.FetchAsync(GeoIpRequest geoIpRequest)
   at Sitecore.CES.GeoIp.Core.Fetcher.GeoIpFetcher.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<<DoFetchFromLookup>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass181_0`1.<<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.CircuitBreakerSyntaxAsync.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<<CircuitBreakerAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.CircuitBreaker.CircuitBreakerEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__181`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<ExecuteAsync>d__121`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Wrap.PolicyWrapEngine.<>c__DisplayClass8_0`1.<<ImplementationAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass181_0`1.<<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Polly.RetrySyntaxAsync.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<WaitAndRetryAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext()
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It logged something as `Sitecore.CES.GeoIp` that leads me towards an investigation for Sitecore device detection and GeoIP lookup.

As Device Detection module is enabled by default and requires access to Sitecore services to download and update the device database. more details here (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-sitecore-device-detection.html)

The Device Detection module is enabled by default. However, if you want to prevent the Device Detection client from contacting the Device Detection service every day (which is the default setting), and you do not need the Device Detection functionality, then you can disable the module.

To resolve this, I disabled the device detection and GeoIP lookup setting with the below patch:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement or ContentDelivery">
    <settings>
        <setting name="DeviceDetection.Enabled">
            <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
        </setting> 
        <setting name="GeoIp.PerformLookup">
            <patch:attribute name="value" value="false" />
        </setting>  
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!